# Insert Message before content of after title

Tags: plugins, title, content

How can I insert custom message after post title. For example

```
The Post Title 
My custom message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use '[the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)' filter

```
function add_before_content($content) {
 return 'Before content area '.$content;
}
add_filter('the_content', add_before_content);
```

It will still be inside the content div. If you want it outside the div you have to edit related template files i.e. single.php or templates/content-single.php. It all depends on which pages you want to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an extra input field.

You can use a plugin for that, like 'more fields'.
With that plugin you can create more fields(like the name says).

You can create a textarea and put a piece of code in your template between the_title en the_content.

You can use as a code for that:

```
<?php meta('custom-field-name'); ?>
```

Good luck!